# Extracting first and last name from a single name field

Tags: algorithms

I'm working with the Twitter API which provides only a single field called name, which includes the full name of a person.

The application that we're constructing requires a first name and a last name.

Now my question is how I am able to extract the first and last name from a single name field.

I know that I can simply just split or explode the string but this won't work if the person for example has first name which consists of more than one word.

Comment: Related reading: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @biffen   I'd go so far as to state *required* reading before implementing anything that treats personal names as anything other than blobs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are lots of simple ways of doing this wrong - read [this](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) to see why. There is **no** way of getting it right programmatically.

That said, some of the wrong ways are not that bad, all things considered. If you can live with making occasional errors and correcting them with a list of exceptions after users notify you, then naive splitting on white space might be the right thing to do. But you must exercise your judgement whether that's the right trade-off for your application.

Comment: I disagree about the ways it can go wrong not being bad.  There are huge variations in how people structure their names.  For any realistic purpose for which you might want to split a personal name into forename and surname, the potential to cause offense to large numbers of people is huge.  Leaving aside the simple problem of people with names structured like "A B C" (is B part of the given name or family name? both are common in different places) there are entire cultures where people place their surname first, either always (e.g. Japan) or only in formal circumstances (e.g. France).

Comment: I wish this post ranked higher in Google than the hundreds of "How to split First and Last names in Excel" articles - as if they will be remotely accurate. *\*facepalm\**

Answer (score -2):

I would consider using a regular expression pattern with grouping to extract only the beginning and the end words.

Comment: this reads more like a comment, see [answer]

Comment: Writing the code is easy. Deciding on which rules to use is the hard part.